# Immutable set-keys in c++0x, where?

Tags: stl, iterator, c++11, containers

I heard in a talk that the keys in C++0x *associative containers* are no longer *mutable*. Before, in C++03, they have been mutable, and only the Standard's text said, that the order or keys must stay the same.

Now, luckily, this is illegal:

```
std::set<int> ss { 2,5,1,6,8,5,8,0,2,4,9 };
auto it = ss.find(4);
*it = 7;  // 'ERROR: assignment of read-only location'
```

**Where is this change reflected in C++0x?** I looked Final Draft, but still see that `find()` and such returns `iterator` -- that sounds modifiable. (And why this is and must be I gan guess: containers like `map` want to allow the *value* beeing modified. What exacly changed to make the *key*-part const?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your information, 23.2.4/5 in N3290 says:

> For `set` and `multiset` the value
>   type is the same as the key type. For
>   `map` and `multimap` it is equal to
>   `pair<const Key, T>`. Keys in an
>   associative container are immutable.

and 23.2.4/6 says:

> For associative containers where the
>   value type is the same as the key
>   type, both `iterator` and
>   `const_iterator` are constant
>   iterators.
>  ...
>  Note:
>   `iterator` and `const_iterator` have
>   identical semantics in this case

Does this quote solve your question?

Comment: If he was watching the talk I think he was (STL Advanced lectures on Channel9 msdn), then the lecturer even shows the exact typedef that desribes precisely your second point.

Comment: indeed, it does. I did not find it. Thanks. But from an other answer I am confused concerning maps: `map` has always had iterators `<const Key, T>`?

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, I watched S.T.L.'s Channel9 talk. But what MS does is only one *implementation*. I also looked at GCC source, and saw that, too. But I could not find it in the specs.

Comment: @Ise: With you good quotes I found similar specs in the C++03 std as well. `map` indeed has always had *value types* `pair<const Key, T>`. Question answered :-)

Comment: @Xeo: Thanks for supplemental information! As you mentioned, they
`typedef`ed the `iterator` using `conditional` and `is_same` in Part 4.
Literally conforming :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `iterator` and `const_iterator` are now specified to be the same. That's the lowdown, not the technicalities, of course, but it's perfectly legal for `set` containers to typedef `iterator` as `const_iterator` in C++0x.

For `map`, of course, then it was a `pair<const K, V>`, so it never had a problem.

Comment: Yep, `iterator` vs `const_iterator` refers to the mutability of the container itself (or the particular view, e.g. pointer-to-const referencing a non-const object) and not the members.

Comment: for `map` iteatror **always** was `pair<const K, V>`?  Then I misunderstood the talk. Hmm.

Comment: got it, yes `map` has always been like this.